# Providing starting values in ASREML (univariate analysis0

Tags: estimation, asreml

Is there a way of providing **starting values** in ASREML **univariate** analysis (**I know how to do it for a bivariate**)

For example , starting values for **grm(id)** and **id** below;

Y1 ~ mu + Var1 + Var2 + Vr3 + Var4 !r grm(id) + id

VPREDICT !define

F phenvar 1 + 2 + 3

F numerator 1 + 2

H herit 2 4

H repeat 5 4